# Debugging deploying full-stack app to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, backend

I've been trying to deploy my full-stack chatkit messenger app from localhost to being in production with Heroku. I'm not sure which changes have to be made within my code for it to run properly on heroku, as I'm currently getting a 404 "Not Found" error.

I've added a Procfile and an App.json file as someone recommended. I'm not sure whether my package.json's Start scripts are to blame, or whether I need to update the URL's of the HTTP requests within my code (from localhost to heroku's site url).

Or if I need to push the app to production and download static files, which I'm not very experienced with. The code is hosted on my Github (https://github.com/aladin94/MyChatterbox). What am I doing wrong?

```
`{
  "name": "react-chat-tutorial",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@pusher/chatkit-client": "^1.0.2",
    "@pusher/chatkit-server": "^1.0.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "lodash.template": "^4.5.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.14.1",
    "npm": "6.4.1"
  }
}
`
```

Comment: Doesn't look like anythings wrong with your start script, I use heroku a lot and i've never had issues with it. How are you deploying to it? Are you using GIT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work like this.

1.

> server.js

```
app.post('/authenticate', (req, res) => {
  const authData = chatkit.authenticate({ userId: req.query.user_id })
  res.status(authData.status).send(authData.body)
})

// if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { // This is your thang, I commented it out to reach a solution, but probably not necessary for you
  app.use(express.static('build')); // 'react-scripts build' places a /build directory at root, not /client/build

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html')); // Removed client here also
  });
// }
```

This ran fine on my machine, bringing up the main screen for your chatterbox app.

2.

> package.json

Add these scripts to your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
  },
```

Heroku will run the npm `postinstall` script once it has uploaded your code and run `npm install` for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the build at the root of the project and change the code to:

`app.use(express.static('build'))
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
  })`

To run the build, you need to add scripts to the package.json: **"build": "react-scripts build"**

Change your static routes **http://localhost:3001/users** to **"/users"**, as the back-end and front-end are on the same server.